# How loud (dB) are BTC ASIC facilities/rooms/shelves?

Tags: mining-hardware, asic, mining-setup

I am just trying to get an idea of how loud (dB) these ASICs are when many of them are grouped up in an area. I know it may vary quite a lot based on the number of ASICs, size of the area, and many other things. But, I just wanted to know if some of you had measured the dB of a a decently sized group of ASICs so I can get a rough idea of how loud they can be when grouped up.